# BSOD Machine Check Excepetion 3rd time

Tags: windows-7, audio, bsod

About once a day for a couple days  in a row now I've gotten the BSOD with Machine check exception as the error. I posted a question earlier and basically came to the conclusion that Bluescreenviewer wasnt giving me enough information, it was just a very blank and generic properties page. Today however when it crashed, it stated a cause and just gave more info in general, hopefully that can be of some assistance to anyone who knows whats wrong.

Quick notes:
- I have not recently installed any hardware or software 
- I'm running windows seven and the only new thing I have are speakers that came with no software, but the BSOD's started happening the day I got them so it's either a major coincidence or it's a sound issue.

The BlueScreenViewer Page: [image]
And the last one if anyone is interested:[image]

Edit 1: 

Today I got another BSOD with a different error code, and this time it completed. I forgot to mention in previous Blue screens it would always freeze as soon as the physical dump was done, and would never restart automatically, but today with this different error code it did restart, thanks again in advance for any helo :)

Third Bluescreen:
[image]

Comment: Can you upload the .dmp file to some sort of file sharing so I can open it in WinDBG? It will give more detailed information.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bk9a8cg7kzx8f1i/112015-38235-01.zip?dl=0